# Object Declaration on a array variable

Tags: php, arrays, class, oop, object

While Looking into a PHP Plugin i saw a line ,

```
$this->banks[0] = new Population();
```

It seems like they are declaring a object in a array variable. What is the use of it?

Comment: This depends solely on how your application / framework use the array. Without proper context, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: To have an array of objects. This is most commonly used with a \Traversable interface for collections. Basically you have a traversable object that can store a collection of other objects of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

For what you described, it seems they're using a common pattern called [`Singleton`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) that is useful in the way that you have all objects and their states accessible from only one common object.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how the PHP plugin works.
The advantage of using a class instead of the array allows you to create function for a better data manipulation (e.g. a population class could have a function `getPersonByName` or `getPersonsByAge` which makes it easier instead of making a new loop each time.